# Can I rebuild Esxi on a new SD card?

Tags: virtualization, sd-card, esxi

I am running ESXi 6.0 on an SD card on a Dell server for testing but it appears there are issues with the SD card. After a series of power failures:

ESXi reboots but new settings are not saved after reboot(eg: cannot change root password, list of VM's can be changed but is not saved)
bootbank is not found
Looking around the net suggests the settings are not saved as any changes are probably saved to a tmp file

Are there commands to rebuild ESXi on the same or new SD card?

Can you relocate/rebuild ESXI to a more durable storage medium like a USB drive?

Comment: ESXi is a hardware hypervisor to run machines.   Would it not make more sense to install it on a proper drive. You can run your Server as a machine inside ESXi

Comment: Should be as simple as cloning the drive.

Comment: @Ramhound Do you mean copying Esxi to a new SD card?  Or are there VmWare commands to rebuild Esxi from the version in memory back to the card?

Comment: You can clone it: https://virtualhobbit.com/2015/11/20/cloning-the-esxi-boot-volume/

Comment: @essjae Thank you, this should be an answer